# Error comes after the second create button

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This error comes after the second time creating a new order, while the first order was created successfully.

It comes if I had a one order and try to to go to create.blade.php again.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `amount_service` where `amount_service`.`order_service_id` = 1 and `amount_service`.`order_service_id` is not null and `order_id` is null limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laundry\resources\views\orders\test.blade.php)
```

**Order table:**

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id()->from(random_int(1000,5465));

        $table->float('vat')->nullable();
        $table->float('without_vat')->nullable();
        $table->float('total')->nullable();
```

**Service Table:**

```
 Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
```

**order_service:**

```
  Schema::create('order_service', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Order::class);
            $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Service::class);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**quantity_service**

```
Schema::create('quantity_service', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('order_service_id');
        $table->integer('value')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
```

**amount_service**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('amount_service', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('order_service_id');
        $table->integer('value')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
```

**Models:**

**Order.php**

```
protected $guarded = [];
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class)->using(OrderService::class);
```

**Services.php**

```
public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->using(OrderService::class);
```

**OrderService.php:**

```
 protected $table = 'order_service';
    use HasFactory;

    protected static $logFillable = true;
    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id',
        'service_id',

    ];

    public function amount()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(AmountService::class, 'order_service_id', 'id');
    }

    public function quantity()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(QuantityService::class, 'order_service_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**AmountService.php:**

```
   use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'amount_service';
    protected static $logFillable = true;
    protected $fillable = [
        'order_service_id',
        'value',
    ];

    public function orderService()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderService::class);
    }
```

**QuantityService.php:**

```
class QuantityService extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'quantity_service';
    protected static $logFillable = true;
    protected $fillable = [
        'order_service_id',
        'value',
    ];

    public function orderService()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderService::class);
    }
}
```

**The blade page:**

```
<template x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
        <tr class="bg-white border-b-2 border-gray-200" >
            <td x-text="index + 1"></td>
            <td class="px-2 py-2">
               
                <input type="hidden"  x-model="field.id"/>
              
                <select type="text"  x-model="field.service"
                    
                     
                        x-bind:name="`serviceOrders[${field.id}][service]`"
                                {{--name="service_id[]"--}}
                        class="input text-center ml-2 px-8 font-semibold">
                    @foreach(\App\Models\Service::all() as $service)
                        <option value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="px-2 py-2">
                <input  type="text"
                     
                                x-model="field.quantity"
                     
                        x-bind:name="`serviceOrders[${field.id}][quantity]`"

                        class="input">
            </td>
            <td class="px-2 py-2">
                <input x-model="field.amount" type="number"
                       x-bind:name="`serviceOrders[${field.id}][amount]`"
                     
                       class="input">
            </td>
            <td class="px-2 py-2">

                                        </svg>
                 <button type="button" @click="removeField(index)" class="w-full"> <svg
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                         class="h-5 w-5 text-red-700"
                         viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                         fill="currentColor"
                 >
                                                <path
                                                        fill-rule="evenodd"
                                                        d="M9 2a1 1 0 00-.894.553L7.382 4H4a1 1 0 000 2v10a2 2 0 002 2h8a2 2 0 002-2V6a1 1 0 100-2h-3.382l-.724-1.447A1 1 0 0011 2H9zM7 8a1 1 0 012 0v6a1 1 0 11-2 0V8zm5-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v6a1 1 0 102 0V8a1 1 0 00-1-1z"
                                                        clip-rule="evenodd"
                                                />
                                            </svg></button>
              </span>
            </td>

        </tr>
        </template>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click="addNewField()">+ Add Row</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
        
</div>

<script>
function handler() {
    return {
        id: '{{count($serviceOrders)}}',
        serviceName:'',
        quantityName:'',
        amountName:'',
        fields: [
            @php
                if($order->services)
$index=0;
foreach ($serviceOrders as $service)
{
     $amount = optional($service->amount()->whereOrderId($order->id)->first())->value;
     $description = optional($service->quantity()->whereOrderId($order->id)->first())->value;

  echo  "{id: $index,quantity: '$quantity',amount: '$amount' ,service: '$service->id'},";
$index++;
}

            @endphp
        ],
        addNewField() {
            this.fields.push({
                id: this.id++,
                quantity: '',
                amount: '',
                service: ''
            });
        },
        removeField(index) {
            this.fields.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me out to fix that error?

Comment: I don't see any column named `order_id` in your `amount_service` migration. Did you meant to write: `whereOrderServiceId(...)` instead?

Comment: @ettdro yes is there any issue of that? can I do it whith better way

Comment: Well, the issue is that in your blade page, you are trying to fetch a column that doesn't exists in your `amount_service` table. I don't know what your purpose here, but I'm pretty sure the line `$service->amount()->whereOrderId($order->id)` is causing the error. It should probably be `$service->amount()->whereOrderServiceId($order->id)`??

Comment: @ettdro thankyou your answer fixis the essue but I got a huge number of rows in the table I do not no why :)

Comment: I couldn't tell either, maybe just remove them if you don't need them anymore